# How to continue after signal emission?

Tags: qt, qml, signals, qtquick2

I'm building a Othello game in Qt quick and C++.
I use this code from QML dialog to start new game, when one player is human, I wait for input. When two players are PC, I face the problem that the GUI will wait for the slot to finish, in PC players the slot call `flipTurn()` (because it is PC, no input to wait for), `flipTurn` is recursive, so the GUI will block until the game end.
I want it to update the board after each move. link for the project:
[reversi project](https://github.com/mdahamshi/reversi/tree/master)

```
myBroker.createGame(blacktypebutton.checkedButton.playertype,
                                                   whitetypebutton.checkedButton.playertype,
                                                    getBlackAlgo(),
                                                    getWhiteAlgo(),
                                                    getBlackDep(),
                                                    getWhiteDep());
                                console.log("finished creating game !");
```

---

```
void Broker::flipTurn()
{
    if(someoneWon()){
        emit gameEnd();
        return;
    }
    emit updateBoard();
    if (currentGame->getTurn() == Constants::BLACK){
        currentGame->setTurn(Constants::WHITE);
        if (currentGame->getWhitePlayer().getType() == Constants::PC){
            currentGame->pcMove(Constants::WHITE);
            flipTurn();
        }
        else
            currentGame->updatePossible();


    }
    else{
        currentGame->setTurn(Constants::BLACK);
        if (currentGame->getBlackPlayer().getType() == Constants::PC){
            currentGame->pcMove(Constants::BLACK);
            flipTurn();
        }
        else
            currentGame->updatePossible();
        return;
    }
    emit updateBoard();

} 

bool Broker::createGame(int blacktype, int whitetype, int blackalg, int whitealg, int blackdep, int whitedep)
{
    currentGame = new Game(blacktype,whitetype,blackalg,whitealg,blackdep,whitedep);
    currentGame->setGameBoard(&gameBoard);
    updatePossible();
    emit gameStart();
}

void Broker::onGameStart()
{
    if(currentGame->getTurnType() == Constants::PC){
        currentGame->pcMove(currentGame->getTurn());
        cout<<"in ongamestart slot"<<endl;

        flipTurn();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this program should be multi-threaded spliting into GUI part and AI part.

Comment: You should not block GUI thread with continuous operations, like in all other frameworks. Move all these actions to a different thread, in QML you can use [WorkerScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-threading-example.html) or QThread in C++

Comment: I don't think this is a problem that requires threading

Comment: I thought about multithreading, but I didn't find any good tutorial with examples that show how to build such thing, any tutorial for showing how to build GUI and split it from logic will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

After each call to `flipTurn()` , so the GUI engine process any waiting signals (in my case the `updateBoard()` signal).
Although it isn't the best solution, it worked well for my homework.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a turn based game, you will just need a different source to trigger the next turn.

Instead of calling `flipTurn()` directly, you call it through Qt's event loop.

Since you probably will want the human in front of the computer to see the game progressing, very likely with a delay.

For example with a single shot timer

```
// instead of calling flipTurn() directly
QTimer::singleShot(500, this, SLOT(flipTurn()));
```

Call next `flipTurn()` after `500` milliseconds.

Comment: tried it, didn't work :(
I use now :  
`QCoreApplication::processEvents();`  
it work well for showing the board after each PC turn, but I can't exit the game, I can click buttons (although with lag, because I used sleep(1) each time the PC play) ,but the program don't exit because the game didn't end yet.

Comment: Don't use sleep on the main thread. And "didn't" work does not provide information to guess what might be wrong